# Wordpress Mobile Version

Tags: iphone, wordpress, mobile, themes

I'm interested in creating an alternate version of a Wordpress site, specifically tailored for mobile devices. (We're talking about iPhones in particular, but something more generic would be cool, too.)

My thinking on this right now is that I'll need to figure out how to serve the content from one Wordpress installation to two different domains, each with a different theme. And then that second theme could be mobile-friendly.

Is this possible? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WPtouch: WordPress on iPhone, iPod, Android, Storm & Pre

More than just a plugin, WPtouch is an entire theme package for your WordPress website. Modeled after Apple's app store design specs, WPtouch makes your WordPress website load lightning fast on touch mobile devices, show your content beautifully, all while not interfering with your regular theme.

http://www.bravenewcode.com/wptouch/

Answer (score 3):

Can't you just detect the user-agent (search for the iPhone Safari UA string and match it) and serve the iPhone theme if it matches, otherwise show the normal theme?

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two plugins that automatically do this (without a second domain). The one I use is [WordPress Mobile Edition](http://crowdfavorite.com/wordpress/). I should add that it comes with a theme that can be modified.